# AngularJS ng-click disables another ng-click error?

Tags: angularjs

I have two ng-clicks in my menu:

One toggles the off-canvas navigation, the other one closes it.

The toggler works fine, but after I click the other one it doesn't work anymore.

**Toggler:**

```
<div class="row menu-bar sticky">
  <div ng-include="'shared/nav.html'" class="nav-bar"></div> // This includes the offcanvas
  <div ng-click="offcanvas = !offcanvas" class=" button hamb-button">
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
```

**Closer:**

```
<div class="offcanvas-container" ng-class="{'offcanvas-container-in': offcanvas}">
  <div class="close-offcanvas" ng-click="offcanvas = false">x</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul ng-controller="PagesCtrl">
      '...'
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could cause this issue?

Comment: `ng-include` creates a child scope. These answers should give you some options to resolve these.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555720/how-can-i-get-rid-of-parent-in-angular/26555867#26555867 This is a common issue which is asked many times everyday here.. :)

Comment: Yeah, I ran in this with a ng-repeat... Thanks still learning AngularJS.

Comment: No problem. Yes it is the same issue.. :)